# SAS - "where variable" versus "where not missing(variable)"

Tags: sas

In trying to make my code more readable, I face the following situation.

Consider a data step in which you want to select only observations which have a value for `variable`.  It seems there are two ways to do this using a [WHERE statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202951.htm): express the variable alone or use the [MISSING](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p06ybg84o0asa4n17l9ieauk58hb.htm) function.

For example,

**Case 1.  Where VARIABLE**

```
data where_var;
  set sashelp.electric;
  where AllPower;
run;
```

**Case 2. Where not missing(VARIABLE)**

```
data where_not_missing;
  set sashelp.electric;
  where not missing(AllPower);
run;
```

These produce the same result.  However, I'm unsure whether this is necessarily the case.

- Are these functionally equivalent?
- Is Case 1 merely [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for Case 2?
- Are there instances when they will produce different results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SAS, any numeric value other than 0 or missing is true. See https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780367.htm for more info.

That means that your Case 1 and Case 2 are not 100% equivalent. If AllPower = 0, the result will be different.

Comment: And just to be clear, `0` not `"0"` is false; _any_ string other than a string of all spaces [which evaluates to missing] evaluates to "true".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine if `AllPower` **has a value** then only Case 2 will work.

Case 1 is selecting records where `AllPower` is **non-zero**. Zero is a value and is not the same as *missing*.

Comment: Case 1 is selecting records where `AllPower` is non-zero and non-missing

Comment: correct - I should have said it is a non-zero *value*.